# Can Puppet be configured like this?

Tags: puppet

**This entire set-up is in INTRANET.**

I am working on SuSe Linux Platform (SLES/SLED). Recently there was package which
had to be updated because of some problem. So this time we could manually go to desktops and update the package one by one.

Since at this time number of desktops were less so it was possible but in coming time number is going to be around 1000 or even bigger. So i was asked to find some thing with which i can seamlessly push over the updates to all desktops connected.

I came across **Puppet** which sounds good to me and it seems it can do this job.

Since this is an **INTRANET** setup so i am planning to have one centralized Server which will have the updates (eg. apache newer version) in certain location (eg : /var/www/updates) and i will make the same server as puppetmaster . And all other desktops will be connected to this centralized server for fetching any update.

Now once i have a certified update in my central server , how should i ensure that the updated package (any rpm/etc) is pushed/installed over to all other desktops ?

***What class shall i write for that ?***

***Can i write any class which fetch rpm from a location (/var/www/updates) and do rpm -UVH xxxxx.rpm on other desktops?***

Please do suggest some other solutions as well if am heading in wrong direction.

Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 5):

Make sure you have a local repo setup (`mrepo`) and point the servers to that (via puppet) then just use:

```
   ensure => latest,
```

..for each app.